# How to combine following regex?

Tags: regex, combinations

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_-]{5,20}$
```

and

```
(?i)^(?!.*?(admin|manager)).*$
```

So the result would be alpha-numeric string with possible underscore or/and hyphen

and following two strings would not be allowed: "admin" "manager" regardless of string position and lettercase

In isolation I understand both, but find it challenging even to start merging them together.

**Input:*_*__*_*__*_*____ Output:**

adminz5    ***_*__*_*__*_*__**    no match(admin is disallowed)

hello12- ***_*__*_*__*_*__** match

helloaDminz5-***_*__*_***_no match(admin is disallowed)

Comment: post example input and output.

Comment: would this be allowed `adfadfafdadmin` ?

Comment: no since it contains admin, it should not be within string regarding the position and letter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace the `.*` with the pattern you want (adjusted for `(?i)`), like so:

```
(?i)^(?!.*?(admin|manager))[a-z0-9_-]{5,20}$
```